# Why I'm seeing two separated details for memory usage of my app? Is it a bug?

Tags: android, memory

I'm making an Android app that access the user files and takes photos.

I've noticed that whenever I check the memory usage I see two of them.

This is only happens with this App, I tested this app on many phones and I see the same thing! It's like duplicated info!

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

I'm not sure if it's normal or something is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out why I'm seeing this , it's because of using " File Provider Paths " to support android 24+ to access the files.